# How to pass data to child controller when interactive pop gesture is cancelled in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

Traditionally the data is passed to a child controller by calling `prepareForSegue`, for example, when a table cell is clicked.

In iOS 7, there seems to be a new navigation idiom, where you drag the left edge of the screen to go back up the navigation stack. It seems like when you just start the gesture, child view is removed and parent is shown, **BUT** if you cancel it by not dragging far enough, it will be cancelled, child view snaps back into place, but there was no `prepareForSegue` call. The data item in the child view at this point is `nil`, which makes me think it's re-created.

How to properly pass data to child view controllers that would both work for segues and this navigation idiom?

Comment: Which direction are you taking about passing data? And what do you mean by "new" child.

Comment: @rdelmar data passing still from parent->child. "new" because it seems like it's destroyed when dragging starts, created anew when dragging is cancelled (except segue isn't run).

Answer (score 3):

You're wrong about the view controller that's being popped by the drag being destroyed, it's not. viewWillDisappear is called as you start to drag, and if it cancels, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are called but not viewDidLoad or dealloc, so no new controller is being created. If you want to pass data back to the controller that appears when you do the drag, you should use a delegate protocol. You can set that controller as the delegate of the one that's pushed when you do the original push (or the segue that goes forward to that second controller). Also, it's not really correct to call these controllers parent and child -- they're both controllers in the navigation controller's viewControllers array. The parent of either of those two controllers is the navigation controller.

Comment: What you say makes sense, and I think I've just realised the problem, and it indeed has nothing to do with view lifecycle, but weak references and data reload in parent view.

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason turned out to be completely unrelated to views lifecycle, but the fact that data items passed down to detail views were stored as weak references.

1. In my code the list view keeps its data in an `NSArray*` property.
2. On transition, detail view is initialised with an item from said array and stored in a weak property.
3. When pop gesture is initiated, list view is shown. In my code, when the list view is shown its item list is reloaded, naturally nulling references in the child view.
4. When the gesture is cancelled, the detail view is presented without segue, with `nil` item.

Solution: change references in details views to `strong`.